# How to tell ggplot several rows belong to one case in a long format dataset with nested variables

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, row, long-integer

I have a dataset in long format in which each participant undergoes two conditions in an experiment (repeated measures) and each condition is composed of a number of trials. Participants scored (`Score`) per condition/group, but also have individual reaction times (`RT`) per trial.

The dataset looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1, 6), rep(2, 6), rep(3, 6)), 
              Gender = factor(c(rep("M", 6), rep("M", 6), rep("F", 6))), 
              Group = factor(c(rep(c(rep(0, 3), rep(1, 3)), 3))), 
              Trial = factor(rep(c(1:3), 6)),
              Score = c(rep(10, 3), rep(20, 3), rep(15, 3), rep(25, 3), rep(18, 3), rep(12, 3)), 
              RT = runif(18)
                 )
```

I wanted to do some plotting to explore the data and focus on the analysis of the score, which is simpler at this stage. The problem I have is that each row in `Score` is not really representing a single case, as it is `RT` the one that are somehow "leads" the row division of the dataset. To be clear, my problem is that if for example I want to plot a bar with the counts per case of `Gender` I would end up with a sum of 18 cases and not 3, as there are in reality.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(Gender)) + 
  geom_bar()
```

I thought that a way to simplify the dataset could be that each RT row represents the mean/median per participant already, but this would involved subdividing my dataset in two and I prefer that this is the last option. In addition, this would not solve my problem as there will be two `Gender` per participant.

I know this has to be simple, but I am having trouble formulating this issue as I am still a newbie in R.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't think I understand the question here. What are you trying to show? What would your final output look like?

Comment: For example, I am interested in knowing how to make a bar graph with counts of Gender without altering the dataset. If I do it at the current state, the count would sum 18 rather than 3, which is the number of participants in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have multiple rows for each `ID` to count the gender keep only unique values for each `ID` and `Gender` before plotting. So you get something like this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% distinct(ID, Gender) %>% ggplot(aes(Gender)) + geom_bar()
```

[image]